# how to wireless debug in ipad mini 2?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9-beta5

i want to debug wirelessly on iPad mini 2.. but there is no option available.can any one help me where i'm doing wrong??

i am using xcode 9.0 beta 5.

my iPad and macbook are in same network.

[image]

Comment: Wireless debugging requires iOS 11 on the device.

Comment: thanxxx brother!!! @MartinR

Comment: after updating to ios11 i m able to debug wirelessly :)